# Only partially retrieved localStorage data

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, local-storage

I'm currently working on a mobile app using Phonegap 1.4.1. On iOS (currently using 5.1) the app won't load all the data from localStorage.

The first time the app is used I set a flag in localStorage like so:

```
window.localStorage.setItem("myFlag", "true");
```

I also set items "ItemA", "ItemB", and "ItemC" in the same way. Each of these key/value pairs are set at different times during the use of the app, so there's no defined order in which they are set.

**My problem is this:**

When I reinstall the app, without deleting the existing copy first, the app no longer sees "MyFlag", "ItemB" or "ItemC" - it *does* see "ItemA". Using `window.localStorage.length` returns 1, when it should return 4. I have exported the app's data files and examined the file__0.localstorage file with SQLite Inspector (app from the app store) and it shows all four key/value pairs.

Since iOS 5.1+ has moved the localstorage to the Cache folder I have implemented the backing up of the file__0.localstorage file as described [here](http://pastebin.com/5881768B). Basically, what that does is copy the localstorage db to the Documents folder on app pause and exit, and back to the Cache folder on execution of webViewDidStartLoad. This part is working fine, so I don't think that procedure is causing the problem (the symptom of the problem existed in the app before I added that procedure).

Comment: Does `window.localStorage.length` look correct before you reinstall the app?

Comment: Yes it does. And printing out the JSON.stringified version of the localStorage object shows all the properties. After reinstalling the app only "ItemA" is shown.

Comment: So this seems as mysterious to everyone else as it does to me?

Comment: I definitely do. Reinstalling the app really shouldn't make any difference. Are you sure it's not related to the fancy localstorage-db moving?

Comment: Yeah. The symptoms haven't changed, and were present before that was implemented. That it only sees one entry in the SQLite DB file while there is in fact 4 entries is, quite simply, baffling.

Comment: What happens if you add a new key to it when it says 1 entry? Does it change to 2 or 5?

Comment: Still says 1, actually. I see a couple of `deny file-write-create /private/var/mobile/Applications/899D71DE-6F...`statements in the device console (these didn't show up in the main console in Xcode). So maybe the problem does indeed have something to do with the copying back and forth of the localstorage, and that the symptom just stayed the same. Maybe the copying causes the owner/permissions to change?

Comment: Never mind - that deny error message must be caused by something else because I now tried moving the statement writing a new test value to the localStorage to a new location in the code, and put a console.log statement immediately preceding it - and there was no error message there.

Comment: I have now checked the file permissions, and I don't really see how they could be causing this specific problem. The permissions on the localStorage file after restoring from the backup in the Documents folder are: 420. Weird permissions. Both group and owner are "mobile", so the app should be able to both read and write. Anyone know why the permissions aren't 660 - and does this affect the readability/writability on the file?

Comment: To clarify: I've also checked the permissions on the localStorage file before the backup/restore maneuver, and they are the same, so backing up and restoring doesn't do anything to the permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a result of the Cordova (Phonegap) bug reported [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-347?focusedCommentId=13233261&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-13233261). So it was a combination of Apple moving the location of the file__0.localstorage file to the Cache directory and an Apple bug where the Bundle ID for apps is changed when upgrading to a new version of an app and a couple of .plist file entries weren't updated to reflect the new Bundle ID.

The proposed fix, posted as an attachment [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-330) didn't quite work out-of-the-box, as the files included referenced CDVInvokedUrlCommand which referenced JSONKit. So downloading the latest CDVInvokedUrlCommand.h and CDVInvokedUrlCommand.m as well as JSONKit.h and JSONKit.m (all from the Cordova GitHub repo) was also necessary. The code in the README.txt file of the Phongap 1.4.1 version of the proposed fix also included an error. It said:

*6) In your app's "AppDelegate.m", replace your "webViewDidStartLoad" function with this:*

```
    - (void) webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView 
    {
        static CDVLocalStorage* localStorage = nil;
        if (localStorage == nil) {
            localStorage = [[CDVLocalStorage alloc] initWithWebView:theWebView];   
            [localStorage restore:nil withDict:nil];
        }

        return [ super webViewDidStartLoad:theWebView ];
    }
```

But it should have said to add the body of the above method to the method you already have with this signature - and the line `[localStorage restore:nil withDict:nil];` should be changed to `[localStorage restore:nil];`, as the former method signature doesn't exist anywhere.

Of course, the proper imports also had to be added to AppDelegate.m.

---

Upgrading to the latest version of Phonegap would be the simplest solution for those who are able to do so. However, we are using the (relatively suddenly) ancient version 1.4.1 and a 3rd party plugin which isn't compatible with newer versions of Phonegap yet - so this fix was the best fit for us.